# Pivot table : Update value in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in my database and I am able to display data according to my requirement. Now I want to update the table's data from front-end with mysql query.

Here is a reference [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90233/1/0)

For example, I will update the value for Alison's monitor.
How I will?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's the problem?  All `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs` interact with the *table* `User_Items`.  All display use the `VIEWs`, which dynamically do the `SUM()` (etc).

Update example:

```
UPDATE User_Items
    SET Item_Amount = 1234.56
    WHERE Cust_Names = 'Alison'
      AND Item_Type = 'Computer';
```

Aside:  Don't use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for money.  Instead, use `DECIMAL(8,2)`.  (Notice in the Fiddle that the values are mangled by FLOAT.)